# Nightmare Ex-Professor Haunt me in my new PhD?

Tags: phd, academic-life

Long story short: I started a Ph.D. in late 2017 and after one year I was forced to leave because of racism/bullying and it was an awful experience, although I was a hard worker and got grants. I moved temporarily to an aloof country with harsh conditions and then out of desperation I accepted a position in another country to turn out they don't any facilities, I resigned since a month ago while in this year I developed a good network with our professors in the field except the bully one who trying destroying me back then. Luckily I got a new position this month with a relatively good professor.

The shock comes here, I cannot believe it: I developed a strong skill while I worked in the lab of bully professor in 2018, and that why they brought me.

I found after starting that they have a collaboration with this bully professor who literally because of him I stuck two years of my life at wrong places because of lack of money and was desperate.

Of course, no one knows about that from the new supervisor because of its old story, he know I resigned from my position and even accept me directly without an interview.

Tomorrow, I have a meeting and that bully supervisor would attend, worse: they won't make very official.

I am shattered, Maybe the unluckiest person in that situation, the problem I cannot even resign now again it is insane, I don't know what the bully ex-supervisor going to say.

You don't know how much time does it to over this experience. Mind you with I got CPTSD and benign tumors in the body after my horrible experience with him.

Honestly: I don't know what to do, I don't want to see him and I cannot bring this old issues since back then this ex-supervisor was trying to blacklist, but luckily I managed to get awards and recognition from my community and that's why I was hired for the new position.

I would be grateful for your advice.

Comment: How unlucky! Nonetheless, remember: your health is more important than your career. No health, no career. I am not usually quick in advocating this (in fact have recently argued against over-use), but this is a case, where you need someone to help you take care of your mental (and physical) health. There is one thing to remember: bullies latch on your perceived weaknesses, like a virus on cell receptors. But, the bully is no longer your boss. You are now facing him, but not exposed to him. You are in a far stronger position now. They need you (you were accepted without interview). Good luck!

Comment: You need to tell your new supervisor what happened to you.  I cannot see any other way to improve the situation.  Give them a minimum amount of detail so that they can arrange for you to avoid contact with the old supervisor.