# My new supervisor wanted to collaborate with my ex-supervisor who bullied and destroyed me

Tags: phd

I was in a lab since two years ago for a PhD and I wasnot lucky since I had faced bullying and all the bad things you could imagine. I left one year and for the bad luck I thought that this would be end, however, I got hired for a new PhD and for irony that wanted to use a software where I had learned since I was there and my ex-supervisor is also well known in our field.

I had another PhD student who literally makes things out of the thin air, he make up things and since I know the topic very well, I know he is a sketchy understanding, but my new supervisor is not really expert in that point in particular. This student brought the idea of collaborating with the guy and tried to make contact with my ex-supervisor.

I felt I am destroyed.I told my new supervisor that the relationship of my ex-supervisor wasnot got to me, and he was quite okay with that, however, after two weeks this PhD student persist on including my ex-supervisor although I am aware of the topic,  this student ignore all what I said for suggestions and is so welcomed by my new supervisor which baffles me. Next week they will have a meeting and this so much pressure to me.

I dont know what to do again! I felt the most unluckiest person on this planet, moreover I am a girl from underrepresented community.

I think this the last shot, my academic aspiration is doomed, I am tired. I dont know what I can do again?

Comment: Whose PhD project is this? If it's the other student's project, you can always decide to withdraw from it for personal reasons. If it's yours, the other student has no business inviting people to it, and you can tell them that you will pursue the project without them.

Comment: Unfortunately! This is European project and we have to contribute in the same project, I feel hopeless.

Comment: Your PhD project does not have to be the project that provides your funding. You can do a minimal amount of work for the latter, and focus on developing your own, independent PhD project.

Comment: It is in Europe and they have the funding for the project, not like US. You have to work in that subject.

Comment: I'm Europe-based and have a good bit of relevant experience. What I wrote before reflects my experience. Your PhD topic is a matter of negotiation between you and your PI. EU projects need to show some results, but if the other student drives that work, well, good for all of you.

Comment: "but if the other student pushes that work, well, good for all of you." It is not relevant to my case as in the end of day I am stuck and as I said he is making stuff out of the thin air.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to my point.

Comment: See related previous post, which was closed as unclear.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149329/nightmare-ex-professor-haunt-me-in-my-new-phd

Comment: If you feel hopeless, you need to speak to a mental health professional.

Answer (score 6):

What will happen depends a lot (too much) on the good will of your new supervisor. But you have to avoid getting trapped again even if you aren't in a good will situation.

You will need to insist to your new supervisor that you cannot work with the old one based on past interactions that you found destructive. Also inform the supervisor that you find the actions and attitudes of the other student to be very unhelpful and that pressuring you isn't going to resolve anything.

Sadly, I can't predict that the outcome will be positive, since I don't know anyone involved here. But, you might also have to consider that you need to find a new situation altogether if the new supervisor turns out to be unsupportive.

But don't make a point of discussing your view of the competence of the other student. That is for others to judge and raising it won't help your case.

You need positive supervisor support and you need to not have to deal with social pressure. The pressure of research should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks Buffy! This is my third time at try the PhD and I thought this time would be the salvation. I will not try to mention the  student competence, but the problem is the supervisor appreciates him alot for instance when I am sharing my work which in the same area of the other studnet, he always not commenting, while the other student posts wishy washy results this supervisor engage. I have the feeling that since I  told him he took an impression might be not good. I am literally exhausted.

Comment: @Erik You mention here this one is your 3rd try at a PhD. I do not know whether it is pertinent to your case, but why did the 1st try (the one that involved neither your present nor your bullying supervisor) fail? Maybe there is something in your strategy that needs fixing, for this we might need to know the backstory.

Comment: After leaving the first one, I didnot find a place to accept me, I traveled to an isolated ciountry in europe with very low payment I stayed six months desparately looking for PhD position. Thanks to my ex-supervisor he said you will never find a position. After six months I got accepted in a program at Europe as well and I thought that would be great, however, the people I worked with are not well known in the field, I accepted out of desparation and BTW in the same area of my research

Comment: My supervisor at the second one has zero knowledge what is the project about, I didnot mind I just worked hard and by the time gone, there is no materials and everyone from the project was complaining, the project coordinator was ignorant and didnnot want to help and she was horrible to lead the project.

Comment: I am hosting kind of famous tec chat in my field and thats why my new supervisor know about me and offered me this position he knows that my second PHD Where I spend one year didnot have any materials to work on.

Comment: Maybe will not believe, but I spend 1 year, 6 months cheap labor, 1 year another program accepted it out of desperation and then leave to a third one where it turned they want to cooperate with the main root.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I think most of the story is documented at this SE site actually, except posted from a number of different accounts at different times (and some of it may have ended up being deleted again).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, yes that is true and that why I think maybe I am the problem because I have never seen anyone in my situation. I think my academic career is doomed.

Comment: It may not be you. Unfortunately some people think they can just dominate "a girl from underrepresented community".

Comment: *"Unfortunately some people think they can just dominate "a girl from underrepresented community".* ---Yes, of course, especially if that girl's name is *Erik*!

Comment: @Dilworth, perhaps you missed the next-to-last paragraph of the question, from which I was quoting.

Comment: @Dilworth I am a female.

Comment: Yes, of course, we all read the OP. I was just noting the peculiarity of a female  nicknamed Erik. Of course, everyone is entitled to freely pick their own name/nickname.